# MS Graph: Attachments doesn't display in message which is attached to another message

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, office365, ms-office, eml

I am trying to send an email with Microsoft graph API and attach email which contains attachments. Here is my code to dynamically create attached email:

```
# Use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id} endpoint and requests library
# render response with json method
message = handler.get_email(email_id)

message["@odata.type"] = "#microsoft.graph.message"

# Use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/attachments/{id} endpoint and requests library
# render response with json method
message['attachments'] = [handler.get_attachment(email_id, attach_id) for attach_id in attachment_ids]

email_attach = {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
    "name": message['subject'],
    "lastModifiedDateTime": message['receivedDateTime'],
    "item": message
   }
```

Then `email_attach` is added to json representation of the message and sent via post request and   `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail` endpoint. The message is successfully sent and received, but attach email doesn't display any attachments.

For testing purpose I attached the same files to sent message and they are displayed normally.
Can anyone clarify why are attachments not displayed in attach message?

Comment: Do you attach the .msg or .eml file? If its .msg file how this file was generated? Can you able to open the .msg file in Outlook (without graph) and it shows the attachment correctly, right?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I get email as a json object with MS Graph get request and `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me//messages/id`. If I save the message with outlook in .eml or .msg and then attach to another email, everything works fine.

Comment: In order to get the MIME Message of the given message you need to use, GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/id/$value.

Comment: Also you can try the following Graph API call if the message is attached to another message in the user's mailbox:  GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value